# MVVM Grouping Items in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. I want to group items in listView. 
In result I want to see something like that:

[image]

It'm using MVVM pattern. It's my XAML code.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="EmploeeGroup"                               
                      Source="{Binding Path=AllEmploees}">
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="FirstName" />
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ListView AlternationCount="2" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource EmploeeGroup}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}" Padding="0,0,0,10">
  <ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" 
                                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                  <Expander.Header>
                    <DockPanel>
                      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                 Text="Name: "/>
                      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                  </Expander.Header>
                  <Expander.Content>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                  </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
  </ListView.GroupStyle>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="150"
                      Header="FirstName"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="150"
                      Header="LastName"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It's my **EmploeeListViewModel.cs**

```
public class EmploeeListViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
  readonly EmploeeRepository _emploeeRepository;

  private ObservableCollection<EmploeeViewModel> _allmpl;
  public ObservableCollection<EmploeeViewModel> AllEmploees
  {
    get
    {
      if (_allmpl == null)
      {
        _allmpl = new ObservableCollection<EmploeeViewModel>();
        CreateAllEmploee();
      }
      return _allmpl;
    }
  }

  public EmploeeListViewModel(EmploeeRepository emploeeRepository)
  {
    if (emploeeRepository == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("emploeeRepository");

    _emploeeRepository = emploeeRepository;
    _emploeeRepository.EmploeeAdded += this.OnEmploeeAddedToRepository;
  }

 private void CreateAllEmploee()
 {
   List<EmploeeViewModel> all =
                (from emploee in _emploeeRepository.GetEmploees()
                 select new EmploeeViewModel(emploee)).ToList();
   foreach (EmploeeViewModel evm in all)
   {
     evm.PropertyChanged += this.OnEmploeeViewModelPropertyChanged;
     AllEmploees.Add(evm);
   }
   this.AllEmploees.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
 }

 //this.OnCollectionChanged;
 //this.OnEmploeeViewModelPropertyChanged;
}
```

**EmploeeViewModel.cs**

```
public class EmploeeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  #region Fields
    Emploee _emploee;
    bool _isSelected;
  #endregion

  #region Constructor
    public EmploeeViewModel(Emploee emploee)
    {
      if (emploee == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("emploee");
      this._emploee = emploee;
    }
  #endregion

  #region Emploee Properties
    public bool IsSelected
    {
      get { return _isSelected; }
      set
      {
        if (value == _isSelected)
          return;

        _isSelected = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
      }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
      get { return _emploee.FirstName; }
      set
      {
        if (value == _emploee.FirstName)
          return;
        _emploee.FirstName = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
      }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
      get { return _emploee.LastName; }
      set
      {
        if (value == _emploee.LastName)
          return;
        _emploee.LastName = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
      }
    }
  #endregion
}
```

- Why can not I bind "FirstName"
  property with Expander.Header
  TextBlock?
- Why have I object type
  MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal
  inside Expander.Header(if i wrote inside 
  Expander.Header 
  Text="{Binding}")>?

How should I
   change my XAML or .CS code to produce
   [these results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zF5o.jpg)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found answer on this question by myself.

The object that is sent into the converter is of the type: MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal.

The main reason is to use "Name" for databinding the group names is simply because that is the property in CollectionViewGroupInternal that contains the name that the current "group collection" has (according to the GroupDescription that you specified).

Not important What was GropertyName in PropertyGroupDescription. 
You have to **always** use {Binding Path=Name} in GroupStyle container.

I had to change only one string in my XAML.

From:

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
```

To:

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

Comment: This is extremely bazaar. I have noticed it here in this post http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/ and thought this might be a typo. Why on earth it should always be "Name" but not the name of the actual binding!!! Cheers mate.

Comment: "Name" is the name of the property that holds the item you grouped on.  You have a group of items all of which share a FirstName and the "Name" property holds that common value.  This becomes more obvious when you group on a complex type.

Comment: I have spent a good 1.5 houre trying to figure why my group names were not showing (but the group itself was correct) and now seeing this answer you have saved me. I'd say this is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same Problem regarding the "Name / FirstName" Binding-Problem and found a solution for my project here:
[Grouping ListView WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918345/grouping-listview-wpf)

In short, withing the Expander-Tag you can set the DataContext to "{Binding Items}". After that you can use your original property names.