# Dynamically creating groups in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am looking for some help in dynamically creating groups in a WPF listview.  In WinForm I would do the following to create the group:

```
ListViewGroup Group1 = new ListViewGroup();
myListView.Groups.Add(Group1);
ListViewGroup Group2 = new ListViewGroup();
myListView.Groups.Add(Group2);
```

and this would create the groups.  I can then do the following to add items to the groups:

```
myListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("Some String1", Group1))
myListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("Some String2", Group2))
```

In WPF I have searched but could not find a way to do this.  Is it possible?
I have already created the list view using the following:

```
<ListView Name="myWPFListView" Grid.Column="1" Margin="9,61,0,20" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="252" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="myHeader" Width="252"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

from here I don't know how to proceed as I would like to create the groups from another class.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use data binding and data template to Bind your data [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918345/grouping-listview-wpf) will help you.